# New registered user to be redirected to the password reset screen

Tags: laravel-5, forgot-password

I'm quite new to Laravel and have been stumped on a problem for 2 days - I'd be grateful for some guidance.

I'm using the default out-of-the-box User authentication system with Laravel 5.3.  A new user is created automatically behind the scenes by an existing Admin user -  I will in time hide the user registration page. I have also successfully set up middleware to check if a user is newly registered (by looking for a null 'last_logged_in_date' that I've added to the migration).

All I want to happen is for a new registered user to be redirected to the password reset screen that ships with Laravel (again, in time I will create a dedicated page). I would like this to happen within the middleware file. So far, my middleware looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

class CheckIfNewUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        if (! is_null($user->last_logged_in_date )) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // This is where I'm stuck!!!

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what code to enter at the location indicated by the comments above. I've tried sendResetLinkEmail($request); etc and have imported what I though were the correct classes but I always end up with a Call to undefined function App\Http\Middleware\sendResetLinkEmail() message irregardless of what I 'use' at the top of my class.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code that gives you the error? I mean the code where you use sendResetLinkEmail function and what you use on top

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think my last attempt was using sendResetLinkEmail($request) with use App\Http\Controllers\Auth at the top...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Well that happens because you have not defined your `sendResetLinkEmail($request)` function yet. You can do it like this, or you can create a new class with that and then call the class.</strike>
Call the trait SendsPasswordResetEmails and then access it with `$this` since traits are not classes and you cannot access their members directly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class CheckIfNewUser
{
     use SendsPasswordResetEmails;
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        if (! is_null($user->last_logged_in_date )) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // This is where I'm stuck!!!
        //EDIT
        //return $this->SendsPasswordResetEmails->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
        return $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but Laravel already gives you the code for the SendResetLinkEmail function - I believe it is a TRAIT. I just cannot for the life of me reference it from my middleware...

Comment: @Ows have you tried `use SendsPasswordResetEmails` on top of your middleware? set it after class declaration

Comment: Thanks again. That makes sense. I am getting closer, but I'm now getting the following error: Undefined property: App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfNewUser::$SendsPasswordResetEmails

Comment: By the way, I moved the use SendsPasswordResetEmails statement outside of the class, as it was generating syntax errors. Is that correct?

Comment: move the `use SendsPasswordResetEmails` statement inside the class again, and call the method directly `$this->sendResetLinkEmail($request)`. Forgot that traits become a part of the class

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm now getting Trait 'App\Http\Middleware\SendsPasswordResetEmails' not found...

Comment: My code at the moment looks like this:

``` <?php

 namespace App\Http\Middleware; 
 use Closure;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Auth; // Is this needed?

class CheckIfNewUser
{

 use SendsPasswordResetEmails; 
  
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {

 $user = $request->user();

 if (! is_null($user->last_logged_in_date )) { 

  return $next($request);
 } 

   return $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
 }
}
```

Comment: your code is ok. Just add below `use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;` the following line `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;`